# Wcf auto-host que permite conexiones a través de Internet

Tags: c#, wcf, web

I need to create a self-hosted WCF service, which allows access through the internet, and it throws this error at me ”System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no end listening on http://fabianwesling.dynu.com:28620/HostManager/Service that could accept the message. The cause is usually an incorrect SOAP address or action. ”
can someone help me what is the mistake I am making, I have opened the ports on the router, router firewall and Windows and deactivate the antivirus

… I show you what I have done.

**Service**

```
[ServiceContract()]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract()]
    int SumValues(int value1, int value2);
}
public class Service : IService
{
    public static void Configure(ServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior
        {
            HttpGetEnabled = true
        });
        config.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceDebugBehavior
        {
            IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true,
        });
        config.EnableProtocol(new BasicHttpBinding() );
        config.EnableProtocol(new NetTcpBinding());
    }

    public int SumValues(int value1, int value2)
    {
        return value1 + value2;
    }
}
```

**Run server local Host**

```
Uri http_Uri = new Uri("http://192.168.1.100:28620/HostManager/Service");
Uri netTCP_Uri = new Uri("net.tcp://192.168.1.100:28621/HostManager/Service");


host = new ServiceHost(typeof(HostManager.Services.Service), http_Uri,netTCP_Uri );
  host.Open();
```

**Run server to access from internet**

```
Uri http_Uri = new Uri("http://fabianwesling.dynu.com:28620/HostManager/Service");
Uri netTCP_Uri = new Uri("net.tcp://fabianwesling.dynu.com:28621/HostManager/Service");
host = new ServiceHost(typeof(HostManager.Services.Service), http_Uri);
host.Open();
```

**client local connection**

```
EndpointAddress uri = new EndpointAddress("http://192.168.1.100:28620/HostManager/Service");
                    ServiceReference1.ServiceClient service = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IService", uri);//http binding
//EndpointAddress uri = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://192.168.1.100:28621/HostManager/Service");
//ServiceReference1.ServiceClient service = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient("NetTcpBinding_IService", uri); ///net-tcp binding
var result = service.SumValues(GetNumber(), GetNumber());
```

**client connection through internet**

```
 //http binding
EndpointAddress uri = new EndpointAddress(" http://fabianwesling.dynu.com/:28620/HostManager/Service");
ServiceReference1.ServiceClient service = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IService", uri);
//net-tcp binding
//EndpointAddress uri = new EndpointAddress(" http://fabianwesling.dynu.com/:28620/HostManager/Service");
//ServiceReference1.ServiceClient service = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient("NetTcpBinding_IService", uri); 
 var result = service.SumValues(GetNumber(), GetNumber());
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify domain name to IP address:

```
EndpointAddress uri = new EndpointAddress(" http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/:28620/HostManager/Service");
ServiceReference1.ServiceClient service = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IService", uri);
 var result = service.SumValues(GetNumber(), GetNumber());
```

Ensure that the IP address is an IP address on the public network.

Comment: Based on the information you provided, I did a test. When the remote client uses the IP address, it can successfully access the WCF service.

Comment: The endpoint address can only be a URI, we cannot use a domain name as an endpoint address.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I made a new query with some changes and following your suggestion ... I would like you to see it and if it is possible to help me with your knowledge ... big hug
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63266705/wcf-self-host-to-access-from-internet