# WCF Self-Host to access from internet

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, webserver

I am trying to create a service to consume it through the internet, but for some reason I cannot access it and I need help finding the error I am making.
I leave the code for you to see.

```
 public class ServiceHost<T> : System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost
    {

        public ServiceHost(Type serviceType, params Uri[] baseAddresses)
            : base(serviceType, baseAddresses)
        {
        }

        public ServiceHost(object singletonInstance, params Uri[] baseAddresses)
            :base(singletonInstance, baseAddresses)
        {

        }
        protected ServiceHost() 
            : base()
        {

        }
        public void EnableMetadataExchange(bool enableHttpGet = true)
        {
            if (State == CommunicationState.Opened)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("La comunicación ya está abierta");
            }
            ServiceMetadataBehavior metadataBehavior
                                = Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();

            if (metadataBehavior == null)
            {
                metadataBehavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
                Description.Behaviors.Add(metadataBehavior);

                if (BaseAddresses.Any(uri => uri.Scheme == "http"))
                    metadataBehavior.HttpGetEnabled = enableHttpGet;
                }
            AddAllMexEndPoints();
        }
        public bool HasMexEndpoint
        {
            get
            {
                return Description.Endpoints.Any(
                                              endpoint => endpoint.Contract.ContractType ==
                                              typeof(IMetadataExchange));
            }
        }

        private void AddAllMexEndPoints()
        {
            Debug.Assert(HasMexEndpoint == false);
            foreach (Uri baseAddress in BaseAddresses)
            {
                Binding binding = null;

                switch (baseAddress.Scheme)
                {
                    case "net.tcp":
                        {
                            binding = MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexTcpBinding();
                            break;
                        }
                    case "http":
                        {
                            binding = MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding();
                            break;
                        }
                    case "https":
                        {
                            binding = MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpsBinding();
                            break;
                        }
                    case "net.pipe":
                        {
                            binding = MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexNamedPipeBinding();
                            break;
                        }
                }
                if (binding != null)
                {
                    AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange), binding, "MEX");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Hosting**

```
        public void HostService()
    {
        try
        {
            Uri tcpBaseAddress = new Uri("net.tcp://192.168.1.110:28620/");
            Uri httpBaseAddress = new Uri("http://192.168.1.110:28621/");
            ServiceHost<wesling.Services.GC> host = new ServiceHost<wesling.Services.GC>(typeof(wesling.Services.GC), tcpBaseAddress, httpBaseAddress);
            //add tcp binding
            var netTcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding()
            {
                MaxBufferPoolSize = int.MaxValue,
                MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue,
                ReaderQuotas = new System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas()
                {
                    MaxStringContentLength = int.MaxValue
                },
            };
            netTcpBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(wesling.Services.IGC), netTcpBinding, "GC");

            //add WSHttp binding
            var httpBinding = new WSHttpBinding()
            {
                MaxBufferPoolSize = int.MaxValue,
                MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue,
                ReaderQuotas = new System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas()
                {
                    MaxStringContentLength = int.MaxValue
                },
            };
            httpBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(wesling.Services.IGC), httpBinding, "GC");

            host.EnableMetadataExchange(true);
            host.Open();
        }
        catch (CommunicationException ce)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ce.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

> The uri ip is the lan ip of the pc where the service is hosted

**The customer is like this**

```
public async void GetProduct()
        {
            try
            {

                var endPointConfiguration = "WSHttpBinding_IGC";//cfg.GetEndPointConfiguration();
                var address = "http://fabianwesling.dynu.com:28621/GC"; //cfg.getAddress();

                ServiceReference1.GCClient service = new ServiceReference1.GCClient(endPointConfiguration, address);
                var bindins = service.Endpoint.Binding;
                if (bindins is NetTcpBinding tcpBinding)
                {
                    tcpBinding.MaxBufferPoolSize = int.MaxValue;
                    tcpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
                    tcpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = int.MaxValue;
                }
                else if (bindins is WSHttpBinding wS)
                {
                    wS.MaxBufferPoolSize = int.MaxValue;
                    wS.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
                    wS.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = int.MaxValue;
                }

             var result =  await service.GetProductsAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

> I opened the ports in the Reuter so that it directs those ports to the pc, and I also opened the ports in the firewall, I also activated the Windows .net framework features. But when I try to connect from the client, it tells me that there was no end listening
> There must be some concept that I am not understanding, but I cannot identify what it is ... I need your advice, everything is welcome

Comment: Have you tried the connection locally ? If work the problem is in: Windows Firewall, Windows Antivirus, Router(s)/Modem(s), Internet Provider, (other appliances like proxy, content filtering, etc) ?

Comment: the service within the lan network works only if the client calls the ip lan of the server ... if you use the url http://fabianwesling.dynu.com/ it is necessary to redirect in the host file in system32

Comment: What mean_ _it is necessary to redirect in the host file in system32_ ? What you have written to the `hosts` file ? The `hosts` file, by the way, is your personal DNS.

Comment: I was trying to say that from within the LAN network it only works using ip or name of the pc where the service is hosted, if you want to use the url. the only way by redirecting the url to the ip from the host file. this is by no means a viable thing I was just trying to emphasize that it doesn't work.
Sorry maybe the translation is not good and my English is bad mastante, I hope you understand

Comment: This confirm that the problem is in your network appliances. Check if the port is open on http://fabianwesling.dynu.com:28621 with a port scanner, check the router logs, check the windows event viewer.

Comment: Thanks for your time, I will be testing what it says and I will comment on the result.  I'm new to webservices and I find it a little difficult to detect where the problems are coming from.

Comment: Use the CanYouSeeMe.org website to verify if my ports are open and it tells me that they are closed, but they are not, it is as if the server is turned off, but it is running and I can use it within the LAN network. the machine is visible on the internet because other stations such as remote desktop are open. To make sure I disable the firewall, antivirus and it doesn't work either. I have more questions than answers so far
I thank you very much for your response and if you have any ideas to contribute it will be welcome. Hug from a distance

Answer (score 0):

First try to use the browser on the client computer to visit http//fabianwesling.dynu.com:28621/GC to see if the metadata can be accessed normally.If not, the client and server cannot access normally. Modify the hots file on the client computer:

[image]

**All in all, you must ensure that the client and server are mutually accessible on the Internet.**

If it is not a network problem, you can create a simple WCF service for testing to know where the problem is.Here is a very simple example of WCF service:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/getting-started-tutorial

**UPDATE**

This is my remote WCF service:

[image]

**Baseadress is the WAN IP.**

**Ensure that the local computer can access the WSDL of the remote service through a browser**

[image]

Comment: I cannot access the metadata from the internet, and if I check my port with the page https://canyouseeme.org/ it says that it is closed. If I run the command "tnc 192.168.1.110 -port 28621" on the pc it says it is open. I opened the port on the Reuter and the firewall. It is possible that I am missing activating a service in Windows perhaps, because I installed the odoo server to test access from the Internet and I cannot do it either. The machine is online because I can access it by remote desktop. I am missing something to understand how to put a web server online

Comment: Try `tnc fabianwesling.dynu.com -port 28621`. I think is closed: problem is on your router, double check settings. Which router/modem model is ?

Comment: I don’t know what is wrong with your network, I suggest you use the IP address to access the service.

Comment: Within the LAN network I can access the service without problems, using the local IP of the machine that hosts the service, if I execute the tnc command to the internal IP of the machine and the port "tnc 192.168.1.110 -port 28621", the The result is "TcpTestSucceeded: True" that is, it is open. To access from the internet I use the public IP, and redirect the port on the router to the PC that hosts the service. The port is addressed, but for some reason my service is not visible. I don't think it's a network problem

Comment: So I suggest you create the simplest WCF service to know if it is a network problem or a service problem:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/getting-started-tutorial

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, I really value your time. I installed a virtual machine with Windows server 2008R2 and I tested the service and it works perfectly from the internet and LAN. The problem only occurs with Windows 10 as I suspected, I did the tests on multiple Windows 10 machines and all have the same problem, there must be some service that I need to enable in Windows 10 to work, but I still haven't found the solution.

Comment: How did you call the service, did you add a service reference?

Comment: Can the client add service references normally?

Comment: Because my remote server is also windows 10, and I have not enabled any additional functions.